# Search first non repeating element in an array:

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, append

[First non repeating element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Md5Ti.png)
)

***can you tell me what wrong with my code?[beginner btw]
I want to make a new array and then append all non repeating elements in it
so the first non repeating element would be arr[0]
output should have 5 here***

Comment: Please add your code as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it like this:

```py
def remove_duplicates(arr):
    counts = {}
    for num in arr:
        counts[num] = counts.get(num, 0) + 1

    unique = []
    for num, count in counts.items():
        if count == 1:
            unique.append(num)

    return unique


input_array = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 5]
result = remove_duplicates(input_array)
print(result)  # Output: [2, 5]
print(result[0]) # Output: 2
```

The first `for` loop creates a dictionary of the elements of your input array to their counts. It will look like this: `counts = {1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 2, 5: 1}`

In the second `for` loop you are taking all the elements with a count of 1 (i.e. the ones that occur only once in your input array) and add them to the array `unique`, which you then return.

You can print the first unique element by accessing the element at index 0.